# GCP Suse Enterprise LInux 15, no default package repository

Tags: sles, packages, zypper

I created a suse linux enterprise 15 vm in GCP. When I try to install anything it gives the following error.

I searched a lot but couldn't find default package repo for suse.

```sh
test-suse:/etc/zypp/repos.d # zypper refresh --services
There are no enabled services defined.
Use 'zypper addservice' or 'zypper modifyservice' commands to add or enable services.
Warning: There are no enabled repositories defined.
Use 'zypper addrepo' or 'zypper modifyrepo' commands to add or enable repositories.
```

Which is default repo for suse linux enterprise? I only want open source softwares like git, ansible etc.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

### Package system and repository configuration

- The guest environment for Compute Engine packages are installed from the packages that are supplied by SUSE.
- SLES instances register with a SUSE run SMT service for Compute Engine and are configured to use SUSE regional mirrors in Compute Engine.

**Note: SUSE images are premium resources that incur additional fees to use.**

VM instances created using Google-provided public images include a guest environment that is installed by default.

To update SLES operating systems, run the following commands:

```
sudo zypper refresh

sudo zypper install google-guest-{agent,configs,oslogin} \
google-osconfig-agent
```

If after run the mentioned command you received an output like this:

```
# zypper refresh
Refreshing service 'cloud_update'.
Warning: There are no enabled repositories defined.

Use 'zypper addrepo' or 'zypper modifyrepo' commands to add or enable repositories.

2019-05-20 18:24:30,404 ERROR:====================
2019-05-20 18:24:30,404 ERROR:Attempt 3 of 3
2019-05-20 18:24:30,404 ERROR:Server 54.244.114.254 is unreachable
2019-05-20 18:24:30,404  ERROR:[Service] Could not find any available SMT server, repo refresh will fail
2019-05-20 18:28:12,873 INFO:Using API: regionInfo
2019-05-20 18:29:12,949 ERROR: Attempted: ['54.253.118.149', '50.17.208.31', '54.244.244.107', '54.223.148.145', '54.247.166.75']
2019-05-20 18:29:12,949 ERROR:Exiting without registration
```

Or

```
2019-05-16 21:24:10,282 ERROR:No response from: 54.247.166.75
2019-05-16 21:24:10,282 ERROR:None of the servers responded
2019-05-16 21:24:10,282 ERROR: Attempted: ['54.244.244.107', '50.17.208.31', '54.223.148.145', '54.253.118.149', '54.247.166.75']
2019-05-16 21:24:10,282 ERROR:Exiting without registration
```

### Resolution

Enable Internet access from the virtual machines to the Public Cloud Update Infrastructure servers. Once the virtual machine has network connectivity to the Public Cloud Update Infrastructure, you can have the on-demand virtual machine register to the SUSE Public Cloud

Update Infrastructure by executing the following command as root:

```
registercloudguest --force-new
```

### Additional Information

The SUSE Public Cloud Engineering team publishes information about the SUSE Public Cloud Update Infrastructure to a REST API. The published information includes server static IP addresses. For customers that have a security policy that allows only external connections to known IP addresses, the published information can be used to create explicit rules for vms to enable SUSE Public Cloud Update Infrastructure communication.

The REST API can be accessed by installing the package `python-susepubliccloudinfo` (pint).

Below are the command options available for pint:

```
pint -h

usage: pint -h | --help

pint (amazon|google|microsoft) servers
[ --filter=<filter> ]
[ --json | --xml ]
[ --region=<region> ]
[ --smt | --regionserver ]

pint (amazon|google|microsoft) images
[ --active | --deleted | --deprecated ]
[ --filter=<filter> ]
[ --json | --xml ]
[ --region=<region> ]

pint -v | --version
```

Comment: Hi @Arden Smith: Thanks for the help. The first command does not work. I see in the /etc/zypp there are no repos available.

Comment: The command output is `sudo zypper install google-guest-{agent,configs,oslogin} \
> google-osconfig-agent
Loading repository data...
Warning: No repositories defined. Operating only with the installed resolvables. Nothing can be installed.
Reading installed packages...
'google-guest-configs' is already installed.`

Comment: I updated my answer. Run  registercloudguest --force-new as root